# PyCharm File Number Denotation

Tags: python, pycharm

I noticed a number inside a square that looks like [9] next to a file that I have in Pycharm Community Edition on the dock on the left side that I do not understand. I am unable to click on it or read any more information about it. I couldn't find anything on Pycharm's website or any of their documentation. I am slightly concerned about this as it could effect subversion if I were to commit this if there is an issue I do not understand.

I cannot show a screenshot as my company is very strict on what can be published to the internet but it looks something like this.

- [python icon]filename1.py
- [python icon][9]filename2.py
- [python icon]filename3.py

This is a unix file with 775 mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a numbered bookmark. You can remove it by selecting the file in Project view and pressing Ctrl-Shift-9.